# Connect to Raspberry Pi using ssh through usb (ethernet)

Tags: usb, ssh, ethernet, pi-zero

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I have configured a proper static IP in `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#set static ip
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.2
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.88.84
```

where `usb0` is the extra interface that appears after plugging my **raspberryPi zero** through the usb. I have set raspberryPi's address being equal to gateway (`192.168.88.84`). I have tried restarting the network:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
sudo service network-manager restart
```

but what I get is

> stop: Job failed while stopping
>
> start: Job is already running: networking

in the first case and

> network-manager stop/waiting
>
> network-manager start/running, process

in the second case.
The command I am trying is:

```
ssh root@192.168.88.84
```

I am constantly getting

> No route to host

Comment: What happens if you change `address 192.168.0.2` to `address 192.168.88.2`? Physically connected IP addresses should be in the same subnet (that is the first three octets/parts of the address should match).

Comment: The address is in one /24 subnet the gateway is in a different /24 subnet. That means the Raspberry will not be able to route anything outside the subnet. If your gateway is at 192.168.88.84 then your RPi needs to have a unique address from 192.168.88.1 to 192.168.88.254 with a 255.255.255.0 (/24) netmask. The alternative would be to use a /17 (255.255.128.0) netmask - but that's unorthodox and not supported with the 192.168.xxx.xxx address blocks.

Comment: Why do you try to ssh to the router with ip address 192.168.88.84? The RasPi has ip address 192.168.0.2. Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Dougie I have configured my RPi with an address of 192.168.88.84. Isn't that ok?

Comment: @Fred I changed the address in interfaces file as you suggested and I restarted the network with the previous two commands that you mentioned but unfortunately when I tried     ssh root@192.168.88.84 it gave me the same error

Comment: @Ingo I have previously configured my raspberry's IP to be 192.168.88.84. Shouldn't     ssh root@192.168.88.84 work?

Comment: Please edit your question and correct the settings in `/etc/network/interfaces` to reflect the current status. But ip addresses must always be unique. If two devices (router and RasPi) have the same ip address it can never work.

Comment: You need to use the same subnet for every machine on your local network. You can't have some machines in 192.168.88.0/24 and others in 192.168.0.0/24 or you'd need a router between them.

Comment: Note though that the subnet of the Pi and the USB Ethernet device should be different of that than your LAN/Wifi. That is, if 192.168.88.X is your Pi connection, then 192.168.0.X (or anything not 88) should be your LAN.

Comment: Follow instruction on following link https://desertbot.io/blog/ssh-into-pi-zero-over-usb
I have done what you are trying to achieve by following the instruction mentioned on the link.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have changed your router's IP address, neither of these look like a normal router address.  192.168.0.1 or 192.168.1.1 are more common: Google your router's name and "default IP address" to find out what it should be, then browse to that IP it to check it hasn't changed.  If it really is 192.168.88.44 then your RPi static address will need to be something like 192.168.88.250.

You are free to choose any static IP address within your subnet, but it's a good idea to choose ones towards the end (avoid 192.168.0.255 as it is the broadcast address), so 192.168.0.250 is good.  You should also configure your router's DHCP to avoid your static address range.

Your RPi config would then look like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

#set static ip
auto usb0
iface usb0 inet static
      address 192.168.0.250
      netmask 255.255.255.0
      gateway 192.168.0.1
```